# Mongoose use both UUID and OID as _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, uuid, objectid

I'm creating a new service to replace an old one.
In the new service I have a model with ObjectId as _id field.
In the old service I have a model with UUID as _id field.

Now I'm having a problem in migrations.
When I migrate the old database into the new, I want to preserve the UUID so both databases will be in sync (the old database will be still used and we will migrate back and forth between them,
so by having the same id in both databases we would know if that's the same record.

When I'm trying to write in mongoose the old record with the UUID into the database I get an error:

```
validation failed: _id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"2fcbd799-d2bd-47c3-8f9a-6900b98ff27b\" at path \"_id\"
```

Mongoose automatically cast the _id string from the rest request into `ObjectId`
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field

I wonder if I can do anything to configure mongoose to accept the UUID as a valid `_id` field,
without overriding the `_id` in the model and replacing it to be `String` type.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks you are trying to convert string to object id

Comment: uuids are not convertable to objectids. If you want to keep both you probably will need to declare your _id field as an object and then handle both type possibilities throughout your application.